# Hibernate trying to set field value to object

Tags: java, hibernate, reflection

Trying to use Hibernate from scratch for first time.
I have entity class:

```
package centaurus.domain;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class Player {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="USER_ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    public Player(){};

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

DAOimpl:
    package centaurus.service;

```
import centaurus.domain.Player;

import restx.factory.Component;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

@Component
public class PlayerDAOimpl implements PlayerDAO{
    private static SessionFactory factory;

    public PlayerDAOimpl() {
        try{
            factory = new Configuration().
                    configure().addAnnotatedClass(Player.class).
                    buildSessionFactory();
            //
        }catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }

    }

    public Player savePlayer(Player player){
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        Integer playerID = null;


        try{
            tx = session.beginTransaction();

            playerID = (Integer) session.save(player);
            tx.commit();

        }catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return player;
    }

    public Player getPlayer(Integer playerId){
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        try{
            Player player = (Player)session.get(Player.class, playerId);
            return player;
        }catch (HibernateException e) {

        }finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

to demo the error i made it add a player on startupscript.

and error:

```
 -- RESTX >> LOAD ON REQUEST << >> DEV MODE << >> AUTO COMPILE <<
 -- for admin console,
 --   VISIT http://127.0.0.1:9091/api/@/ui/
 --

2016-05-31 21:42:48,901 [main            ] [          ] INFO  restx.Apps - can't enable Apidocs doclet: make sure tools.jar is in your classpath
2016-05-31 21:42:49,978 [pool-1-thread-1 ] [          ] INFO  restx.classloader.CompilationManager - compilation finished: 12 sources compiled in 1.015 s
2016-05-31 21:42:50,061 [main            ] [          ] INFO  restx.Apps - can't enable Apidocs doclet: make sure tools.jar is in your classpath
2016-05-31 21:42:50,078 [main            ] [          ] INFO  restx.classloader.CompilationManager - watching for changes in [src/main/java, src/main/resources]; current location is /home/arthur/elorhia/api/.
2016-05-31 21:42:50,145 [main            ] [          ] INFO  org.hibernate.Version - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.1.0.Final}
2016-05-31 21:42:50,146 [main            ] [          ] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2016-05-31 21:42:50,147 [main            ] [          ] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2016-05-31 21:42:50,802 [main            ] [          ] INFO  o.h.annotations.common.Version - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2016-05-31 21:42:50,851 [main            ] [          ] WARN  org.hibernate.orm.connections - HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
2016-05-31 21:42:50,856 [main            ] [          ] INFO  org.hibernate.orm.connections - HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost/andromeda]
2016-05-31 21:42:50,857 [main            ] [          ] INFO  org.hibernate.orm.connections - HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=api, password=****}
2016-05-31 21:42:50,858 [main            ] [          ] INFO  org.hibernate.orm.connections - HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
2016-05-31 21:42:50,860 [main            ] [          ] INFO  o.h.e.j.c.i.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl - HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
2016-05-31 21:42:51,090 [main            ] [          ] INFO  org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
2016-05-31 21:42:51,321 [main            ] [          ] INFO  o.h.validator.internal.util.Version - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.1.Final
START SCRIPT!
org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.String centaurus.domain.Player.email] by reflection for persistent property [centaurus.domain.Player#email] : centaurus.domain.Player@507b79f7
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.getForInsert(GetterFieldImpl.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getPropertyValuesToInsert(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:521)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.getPropertyValuesToInsert(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:228)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getPropertyValuesToInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4701)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:254)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:682)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:674)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:669)
    at centaurus.service.PlayerDAOimpl.savePlayer(PlayerDAOimpl.java:39)
    at centaurus.Dbmaintain.start(Dbmaintain.java:26)
    at restx.factory.Factory.start(Factory.java:846)
    at restx.RestxMainRouterFactory.build(RestxMainRouterFactory.java:450)
    at restx.RestxMainRouterFactory.newInstance(RestxMainRouterFactory.java:70)
    at restx.servlet.RestxMainRouterServlet.init(RestxMainRouterServlet.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:519)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:747)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:492)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at restx.server.JettyWebServer.start(JettyWebServer.java:109)
    at restx.server.JettyWebServer.startAndAwait(JettyWebServer.java:114)
    at centaurus.AppServer.main(AppServer.java:30)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field centaurus.domain.Player.email to centaurus.domain.Player
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:393)
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:39)
    ... 40 more
2016-05-31 21:42:51,673 [main            ] [          ] INFO  restx.monitor.MetricsConfiguration - registering Metrics JVM metrics
2016-05-31 21:44:41,646 [pool-2-thread-1 ] [          ] INFO  restx.classloader.CompilationManager - compilation finished: 1 sources compiled in 86.94 ms
```

it looks like its trying to set the email field to the player object.
I cant work out why!, what have I done wrong?

EDIT: as requested i have added the code creating the player and calling the dao

```
package centaurus;

import centaurus.domain.Player;
import centaurus.service.PlayerDAO;
import centaurus.service.PlayerDAOimpl;
import restx.factory.AutoStartable;
import restx.factory.Component;

import javax.inject.Named;


@Component
public class Dbmaintain implements AutoStartable{
    private PlayerDAO playerDAO;

    public Dbmaintain(@Named("PlayerDAOimpl") PlayerDAO playerDAO) {
        this.playerDAO = playerDAO;
    }

    public void start(){
        System.out.println("START SCRIPT!");

        //test
        Player p = new Player();
        p.setEmail("test");
        playerDAO.savePlayer(p);

        try {
         //  URL configurationUrl = new File("dbmaintain.properties").toURI().toURL();
          // MainFactory mainFactory = new MainFactory(configurationUrl);
          // DbMaintainer dbMaintainer = mainFactory.createDbMaintainer();
          // dbMaintainer.updateDatabase(false);
        } catch(Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

edit added git link if people wanted other bits:
https://github.com/ArthurGibbs/Centaurus-

Comment: Please show the code where you're populating your player object.

Comment: A wise tip: `SessionFactory` is an expensive object. You should not create it for each `DAO` implementation. Instead, define a `HibernateUtil` class and define a static object of `SessionFacory` there and use that object each time you require it from there.

Comment: how do i get around addAnnotatedClass, with hibernateUtil class , the only tutorials i have found are either have bean mappings or specify the class in the factory

Comment: I have added a hibernate utils class, i added the mapping the the hibernate config via linking the annotated class

Comment: @Arthur I also facing the same issue. Did you able to fix  this ?

Answer (score 0):

How are you setting/creating your `Player`?

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field centaurus.domain.Player.email to centaurus.domain.Player
```

This says, that there is an attempt to store object of class `centaurus.domain.Player` into a String field. For futher explanation, attach che actual code that is modifying/creating player perfore passing it to `DAO`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have added the code as requested, i have the feeling its hibernate doing the incorrect setting, probably due to something weird i have done.

Comment: @Arthur you are right, notting fancy can be done here. Try cleaning your env. Shutdown webserver, remove deployment, clean and rebuild the project and finally try to do fresh deployment.

Comment: same error after cleaning all that can be cleaned. the mystery continues.

Comment: @Arthur this can be a problem. I am programmer, not a wizzard:) But have faith, most probably somebody will have the answer to your issue. The only essence is the time...
To be honest I have no idea what could cause such exception in your situation. It would be wise of you to run the debugger and trace the code step by step to check why hibernate wants to set String field's value as Player object

Comment: Bit of delay, (spare time coding project) i debugged the code and it appears to throw on the declaring line of org.hibernate.internal.sessionimp.class save() ,, ie before the first line.   maybe some weird interceptor stuff going on?

Comment: @Arthur even so, interceptors are still standard code and you should be able to debug it as well. I dont understand what do you mean by: "org.hibernate.internal.sessionimp.class save() ,, ie before the first line. " it would be much better to edit your post, paste related code, and pinpoint where actual exception is beeing thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I have used your exact class `Player` to execute this piece of code and got no error at all. A row is inserted in table USERS correctly.

```
public class TestPlayer {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("TestDB");

    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    Session session = (Session) em.getDelegate();

    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

    try {

        Player p = new Player();
        p.setEmail("email");

        session.save(p);

        tx.commit();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        em.close();
        emf.close();
    }

}
}
```

The problem is not in the entity class. Maybe some changes that you made do not refresh correctly on deploy.